# Mudar estilo dos ultimos dois caracteres da string

Tags: javascript, jquery, css

Considerando:

```css
strong {font-size: 36px}
```

```html
    <div id="conteiner">
       <div class="meu-valor">
          <strong>125,74</strong>
       </div>
        
       <div class="meu-valor">
          <strong>125,54</strong>
       </div>
    
       <div class="meu-valor">
          <strong>125,84</strong>
       </div>
    
       <div class="meu-valor">
          <strong>125,90</strong>
       </div>
    
       <div class="meu-valor">
          <strong>126,65</strong>
       </div>
    </div>
```

Como eu poderia fazer para mudar apenas o estilo dos três últimos caracteres da string entre a tag strong?
Isso usando javascript, jquery ou css...

Desde já agradeço pela ajuda!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Podes usar assim:

```
document.querySelectorAll('.meu-valor strong').forEach(el => {
  const [int, dec] = el.textContent.trim().split(',');
  el.outerHTML = `<span>${int}<strong>,${dec}</strong></span>`;
});
```

O que isso faz é substituir o HTML desse `strong` original por outro como vêz na template string. Assim, sabendo todos os `strong` que queres mudar, podes substituir um a um.

```js
document.querySelectorAll('.meu-valor strong').forEach(el => {
  const [int, dec] = el.textContent.trim().split(',');
  el.outerHTML = `<span>${int}<strong>,${dec}</strong></span>`;
});
```

```css
strong {
  font-size: 36px
}
```

```html
<div id="conteiner">
  <div class="meu-valor">
    <strong>125,74</strong>
  </div>

  <div class="meu-valor">
    <strong>125,54</strong>
  </div>

  <div class="meu-valor">
    <strong>125,84</strong>
  </div>

  <div class="meu-valor">
    <strong>125,90</strong>
  </div>

  <div class="meu-valor">
    <strong>126,65</strong>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Poxa... muito bom! Obrigado pelo feedback. Vou estudar mais pra compreender esse código com perfeição. Mas muito obrigado mesmo.

Answer (score 0):

Aqui tem um exemplo utilizando o Jquery. Ele vai pegar o conteúdo dentro do strong e criar um novo HTML. No exemplo, foi aplicada uma tag font para mudar a cor dos 3 últimos caracteres.

```html
<script
  src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.4.0.min.js"
  integrity="sha256-BJeo0qm959uMBGb65z40ejJYGSgR7REI4+CW1fNKwOg="
  crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<style type="text/css">  
strong {font-size: 36px}
</style>
<div id="conteiner">
       <div class="meu-valor">
          <strong>125,74</strong>
       </div>
        
       <div class="meu-valor">
          <strong>125,54</strong>
       </div>
    
       <div class="meu-valor">
          <strong>125,84</strong>
       </div>
    
       <div class="meu-valor">
          <strong>125,90</strong>
       </div>
    
       <div class="meu-valor">
          <strong>126,65</strong>
       </div>
    </div>
 
<script type="text/javascript">
$( document ).ready(function() { 
   $('strong').html(function(idx, oldHtml) {
    var startStr = oldHtml.substring(0, oldHtml.length - 3);
    var endStr = '<font color=#FF0000>' + oldHtml.substring(oldHtml.length - 3) + '</font>'
    return startStr + endStr;

});
});

</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

## Use uma função jQuery

Um exemplo de função jQuery para mudar o estilo CSS dos X últimos caracteres dentro de uma determinada tag HTML.

```
// tagName é o nome da tag html que você quer mudar
// classNames é uma string com todas as classes CSS que serão aplicadas aos caracteres
// howMuch é o número de caracteres do final da tag que vestirão as classNames
function modifyLastChars(tagName = 'strong', classNames = '', howMuch = 0) {

    $(tagName).each((index, element) => {
        let content = $(element).text().trim();
        let breakPoint = content.length - howMuch;
        let initialCaracters = content.substring(0, breakPoint);
        let lastCaracters = content.substring(breakPoint);

        $(element).html(
            initialCaracters +
            '<span class="' + classNames + '">' +
                lastCaracters +
            '</span>'
        );
    });
}
```

## Como usar

```
$(document).ready(() => {
    modifyLastChars('strong', 'uma-classe-css outra-classe-css', 2);
});
```

#### Esse exemplo de uso vai colocar as classes css escolhidas nos últimos dois caracteres (os dois números depois da vírgula) de todas as tags strong do seu HTML.